# Logic problem that i am struggling with

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

$1$-   The universal set for this problem is the set of students attending Miskatonic University. Let

-$M$ denote the set of Math majors.

-$CS$ denote the set of Computer Science majors.

-$T$ denotes the set of students who had a test on Friday.

-$P$ denotes those students who ate pizza last Thursday.

Using only the set theoretical notation we have following assertions

$1$. Computer Science majors had a test on Friday $$CS \subseteq T$$

$2$. No Math majors ate pizza last Thursday-----> $$M^c \subseteq P$$ or $$M \cap P=\varnothing$$ (The book said that the answer is $M \cap P=\varnothing$, idk why?)

$3$. Some Math majors did not eat pizza last Thursday$$C^c \cap P=\varnothing?$$ I am struggling with translating context to symbols.

$4$. Those Computer Science majors who did not have a test on Friday ate pizza on Thursday
$$CS^c \in T \subseteq P?$$
$5$. Math or Computer Science major who ate pizza on Thursday did not have a test on Friday
$$M \cup CS \subseteq P \land T = \varnothing?$$

I need help please. I am trying my best to learn the logic and operations on sets.

I understand that $A \cup B$ reads "$x \in A$ or $x \in B$"; $A \cap B$" means $x \in A$ and $x \in B$" but when it comes to question like this, I have no clue how to write. For instance, $(2)$, how is $M \cap P = \varnothing$? Why can't it be $M^C  \subseteq P$? How does "and" or" "E" used to write symbols?

Comment: to write formulas you simply put dollar signs on each side of the formula and then inser the code for the symbols $\in$ is \in, $\cup$ is \cup, $\cap$ is \cap, $\emptyset$ is \emptyset and $\neq$ is \neq for more information on typesetting symbols check [lshort](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf) for a friendly intro to LaTeX

Answer (score 1):

$(1)$ is correct.

$(2)$ is $M\cap P=\varnothing $ Since $M\cap P$ are the Math Majors who ate Pizza last Thursday.

$(3)$ is $M\cap P^c\ne\varnothing $ Since $M\cap P^c$ are the Math Majors who did not eat Pizza last Thursday.

$(4)$ is $(CS\cap T^c)\subseteq P $ Since $CS\cap T^c$ are the Computer Science Majors who did not have test on Friday.

$(5)$ is $((M\cup CS)\cap P)\subseteq T^c $ Since$((M\cup CS)\cap P)$ are Math or Computer Science Majors who ate Pizza last Thursday.

Comment: how can you assume that those students who ate pizza last Thursday is math majors?

Comment: $M$ is the set of Math Majors and $P$ is the set of students who ate Pizza last Thursday. Hence $M\cap P$ is the set of Math Majors who ate Pizza last Thursday. And according to $(2)$ it should be a null set since there are no math majors who ate pizza last Thursday.